# Strongly typed Linq filtering method

Tags: c#, linq, strong-typing, service-layer

I am a bit tired of writing lines of service layer codes like these:

Below codes just an example for readers. So they may have errors or typos, sorry about it :)

```
//ViewModel
public class EntityIndexFilterPartial
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatusList { get; set; }
    public int? StatusID { get; set; }
}


//Service Layer method
//Method parameters are reperesents view model properties
public IQueryable<Entity> FilterBy(int? id, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, int? statusId)
{
    var filter = _db.Entities.AsQueryable();
    if (id.HasValue)
        filter = filter.Where(x => x.Id == id.Value);
    if (startDate.HasValue)
        filter = filter.Where(x => x.StartDate >= startDate.Value);
    if (endDate.HasValue)
        filter = filter.Where(x => x.EndDate <= endDate.Value);
    if (statusId.HasValue)
        filter = filter.Where(x => x.EntityStatus.StatusID == statusId);
    return filter;
}
```

I search pretty enough for some smart designed codes. I know about **Dynamic LINQ library** and I use it too. But I'm looking for **strongly typed filtering**. 
I don't want to write magic strings or some sort of them.

So basically I found some solutions but I want to hear from this community for some well written smart codes. Of course there may be dozens of solutions but again how would you write your strongly typed filtering service layer codes. Any ideas...

Here are few of my solutions:

**Solution 1:**
Same FilterBy method but parameters are different, now taking expression list. So this means I'm creating predicateList in controller and send it to here.

```
public IQueryable<Entity> FilterBy(List<Expression<Func<Entity,bool>>> predicateList)
{
    var filter = _db.Entities.AsQueryable();
    foreach (var item in predicateList)
    {
        filter = filter.FilterBy(item);
    }
    return filter;
}
```

**Solution 2:**
FilterBy method taking the EntityIndexFilterPartial as parameter in Application Service layer(not domain service). I'm sure this design has some problems, but I want to hear your opinions.

```
public IQueryable<Entity> FilterBy(EntityIndexFilterPartial filterPartial)
{
    //I'm calling the domain service layer FilterBy method such as like in solution 1.
}
```

**Solution 3:**
I think this one much better than others but I'm still thinking for something more simple and better codes.

```
//helper class
public static class FilterByHelper
{
    public static IQueryable<T> If<T>(this IQueryable<T> filter, bool condition, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        if (condition)
            return filter.FilterBy(predicate);
        return filter;
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> FilterBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> filter, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return filter.Where(predicate);
    }
}


public IQueryable<Entity> FilterBy(int? id, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, int? statusId)
{
    return _db.Entities
        .If(id.HasValue, x => x.Id == id.Value)
        .If(startDate.HasValue, x => x.StartDate >= startDate.Value)
        .If(endDate.HasValue, x => x.EndDate <= endDate.Value)
        .If(statusId.HasValue, x => x.EntityStatus.StatusID == statusId);
}
```

I know this became a bit long question but I hope I clearly ask what I want to ask.

**As a quick and simple question do you know any smartly designed code for saving us from writing same lines of these filtering codes?**

Btw, I'm not looking for desing pattern solutions or huge answers, you can give me some example or say how to find the better path is enough.

Of course If you write a full explained response I will be appricated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this If working different than already FindAll(predicate) method ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried simple `||` conditions?

```
return _db.Entities
    .Where(x => id == null || x.Id == id.Value)
    .Where(x => startDate == null || x.StartDate >= startDate.Value)
    .Where(x => endDate == null ||  x.EndDate <= endDate.Value)
    .Where(x => statusId == null || x => x.EntityStatus.StatusID == statusId);
```

? I would expect that after query optimization, the no-op filters would be equivalent to not adding the filters at all.

Comment: +1 It's nice trick. Can you suggest a better solution for service layer method parameters. One part of my question about getting rid of that parameters. Thank you :)

Comment: @YusufUzun: Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean, I'm afraid. How would you pass the filters without any parameters?

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok, my bad. In solution 2 I sent my ViewModel as a parameter to my Service Layer. But we know it's not a good architecture design, right? And also I don't want to write every filtering property as a method parameter like in solution 3. Can you suggest something different for this case.

Comment: @YusufUzun: Not really - I think you need to at least think about *how* you want to provide filters before we can suggest how to implement that idea.

Comment: @JonSkeet As far as I understand from your response, you are saying put your **filtering info** to somewhere else than your viewmodel. Something like keeping in database or filtering objects are part of domain layer? Did I understand right?

Comment: @YusufUzun: I didn't say anything like that. I'm saying you should ignore implementation for the moment, and work out what you want the *calling* code to look like. You want to express the filters, right? So work out how and where you want to express them, and then the implementation may well follow simply.

Comment: Ok, I got it :) . We write filter conditions in application layer, so this means I have to send it from controller to service layer. Which one do you think is right: Sending viewmodel as a parameter or sending each filter property as a parameter to the service layer?

Comment: @YusufUzun: I would potentially send an entirely different type down: a type *specifically* for filtering. After all, you may well not want to filter on all properties, and it's not like you're wanting to express the ViewModel itself - you're trying to express filtering criteria.

Comment: Ok thanks alot, I think I got the main idea. But it's an another question subject I think :) You are saying there must be another generic object only works for Filtering Operations. ViewModel --> Filtering Object --> service method. Sorry for headache :)

Comment: @YusufUzun: Well I'm saying that's an *option*. I wouldn't particularly make it a generic type though...

Answer (score 3):

I solve this problem by using fluent extension methods. I feel this is a pretty nice solution to this particular class of problem. The nice thing about using a fluent style of defining your filters is that it produces some really readable code when you actually consume it. What this does in practice is it makes your service layer a bit more dynamic.

for example

If you were to have

```
public class User {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public DateTime CreatedOn {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public DateTime BirthDate {get;set;}
}
```

you could write some filters similar to this

```
public IQueryable<User> OlderThan(this IQueryable<User> users, DateTime olderThan){/*implementation*/}

public IQueryable<User> CreatedAfter(this IQueryable<User> users, DateTime createdAfter){/*implementation*/}

//or something more generic
public IQueryable<User> WhereName(this IQueryable<User> users, Expression<Func<string,bool>> nameQuery){/*implementation*/}
```

and then chain these things togeather like so:

```
users
    .CreatedAfter(new DateTime(2011,1,1))
    .OlderThan(new DateTime(1985,1,2))
    .WhereName(n=>n.StartsWith("L"));
```

this allows your filtering logic to be a bit more dynamic without creating catchall style filters which are hard to maintain and complex

In practice this means

- Filters can be very simple
- you can create aggregation filters which apply another filter internally
- Filters perform only a single purpose
- they can have business relevant names

In my blog I talk about this method with some real examples. http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2013/2/25/a_case_for_generic_repositories

Comment: +1 Interesting idea, so you are saying create one fluent extension method for each filtering on that domain object. But doesn't it make our code more. However it makes easy to maintain and understandable. Unfortunately, most of developers don't want to write such conditions like these. Are you using those methods in controller or in service layer?

Comment: I accepted @JonSkeet answer because comments sent me to the better approach than mine. But this is also very nice approach and I like this too. Unfortunately there are lots of developers out there who doesn't want to write these for each property. I'll try make it generic. Thank you :)

Comment: @YusufUzun I personally use these right down at the controller however many people don't like using queriables at that level so would enumerate the collection at a different tier. In terms of code volume, i don't think this method produces much more code physically, its just broken down in a different way. You will end up with more methods but each one will be much simpler. Its a trade off either way but this is the way I personally like to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Yusuf This post may be Helpfull for you .Solution looks smart,It implements dynamic where conditions to linq query and looks simple.

http://amitech.co/amitech-lab/item/dynamically-add-conditions-in-linq

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi @hkoseoglu, thats another nice usage. I use PredicateBuilder in my projects either. But it still doesn't respond my requirements for this question. Thanks for reminding.